# How to find the set of binary symbols that can most efficiently compress using Huffman coding?

Tags: algorithm, compression, complexity-theory, huffman-code

In my current implementation of file compression using Huffman coding, I take the frequency of each byte and build the tree from there.

I'm thinking that there is a possibility for further compression if I don't limit the program to only counting the frequencies of bytes but of binary symbols of any length.

For example, in a text file, if there was a "q" and the next byte was always a "u". Instead of using "q" and "u", it would be better to have "qu" and "u".

But instead of just concatenating bytes, any sort of binary symbol of any length.

I have thought to generate all possible messages, then somehow choose a subset of symbols that don't overlap using some sort of Mealy machine implementation and generate frequencies, but I'm at a loss.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: For strings like `qu` you'd usually use some LZ-based compression instead of Huffman encoding.

Comment: @MarkAdler What partition function would create disjoint binary symbols such that, when the symbols are encoded using Huffman coding, they achieve optimal compression?

Comment: @JerryCoffin Is there anyway to combine LZ-based compression with Huffman encoding to achieve higher compression?

Comment: Yes, it's pretty common to do Huffman compression, then LZ compression on the result.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I think you got them swapped there

Comment: @harold: Could be--I'm going from (distant) memories.

Comment: Nearly all of the commonly-used general-purpose compressors use LZ followed by some entropy coding, e.g. Huffman coding (gzip), range coding (xz), assymetric numerical coding (zstd).

Comment: Any question with "... achieve optimal compression" will be no, since it is provably not computable to optimally compress. (See Kolmogorov complexity.)

Comment: @MarkAdler How about the question of, in a sequence of DNA code ("ATCGGCTAC...") of finite length, how would one find the set of patterns such that every element in the DNA code was covered, and every partition had the highest length and frequency?

Comment: That's a perfect application of LZ + entropy coding. There will be repeated sequences of nucleotides, including repeated sequences of amino acid codes. I would start with the symbols being groups of three, coding every three nucleotides in one byte. (Look for disallowed groups to make sure you're synced up on the correct boundary of three.) Then use a standard compressor on that, which will treat the bytes as symbols, and look for repeated sequences of symbols.

Comment: LZ is more efficient at compressing common sequences of symbols than entropy coding, so there is no point in trying to make symbols longer than three nucleotides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem researched by Kolmogorov, Solomonoff, Chaitin, and others in 1960 - 1970. [Wikipedia gives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) a good overview, you can find the original papers from there. Kolmogorov complexity deals with the idea of finding the shortest program length that can reproduce a given arbitrary input string. The term "arbitrary" means *any* input, including infinitely many and random input.

One key point in the study of Kolmogorov complexity is that it's fundamentally impossible to write a single, generic program that can compress arbitrary input strings to a size smaller than the input string itself plus some bytes. This limitation comes from the very nature of arbitrary - random noise data. Random data cannot be compressed. However, if you have specific knowledge about the internal structure or patterns within the data, you may be able to design a more efficient algorithm than the generic lossless compression or [provide better arguments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/562818/510780) to the existing algorithm.

As a practical approach, you can experiment with different general-purpose lossless compression algorithms and check their performance on your data. Try varying compression levels and dictionary sizes. Better compression would usually impact the time it takes to compress data.

In some cases, if you have many short strings with repetitive data, you could try [training compressor](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/zstd/zstd.1.en.html#train%7E2) and use an already pre-computed dictionary to make the compression run faster with smaller output.

From comments I noticed this may be related to DNA sequence compression - this is a separate active area of research, and there are [many papers](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=DNA+compression&btnG=) available on the topic. I would start from there.